# Show html from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show some html element from javascript in #muncul, but it's just error

Here's my code
Are my code wrong?
Sorry for my bad English

```
if(data.st == 0)
{
 $('#muncul').'<div class="ui info message uk-margin-small-bottom"><i class="close icon"></i><div class="header">'.html(data.msg).'</div></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if(data.st == 0)
{
 $('#muncul').html('<div class="ui info message uk-margin-small-bottom"><i class="close icon"></i><div class="header">' + data.msg + '</div></div>');
}
```